# Access PHP variables in a shell script without executing the script

Tags: bash

I want to access variables by running a  PHP script in a shell script,so that I can assign those variables to shell scripting variables.I found some examples while I search through the internet but no luck.Can anyone please help me?

```
read -r DB_SERVER_USERNAME DB_SERVER_PASSWORD < <(/var/www/html/myApp/db/db_credentials.php)

variable1="$(grep -oE '\$variable1 = .*;' /var/www/html/myAPP/db/db_credentials.php | tail -1 | sed 's/$variable1 = //g;s/;//g')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script, but this not so generic so you need in before the variable name in your PHP file.

Suppose you PHP file contain like this

```
$DATABASE=test
$DATABASE_HOST=test.com
$DATABASE_PASS=123
$DATABASE_USER=test
```

Now, The bash script will grep value based on these variables names.

```
#!/bin/bash
# php file to get variables from
FILE_NAME="connection.php"
# this will grep variable from connection file have name start with DATABASE= and will get the lef value of equal sign
DATABASE=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\$DATABASE=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-) 
DATABASE_HOST=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\$DATABASE_HOST=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
DATABASE_PASS=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\$DATABASE_PASS=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
DATABASE_USER=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\$DATABASE_USER=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
echo "Value from PHP file"
echo "Database name ${DATABASE}"
echo "Database host ${DATABASE_HOST}"
echo "Database pass ${DATABASE_PASS}"
echo "Database user ${DATABASE_USER}"
# you can use now these variable in bash
# verfiy once variable values
echo "mysql -h $DATABASE_HOST -u $DATABASE_USER -p$DATABASE_PASS"
mysql -h $DATABASE_HOST -u $DATABASE_USER -p$DATABASE_PASS
```

Comment: Thanks Adiii,that works! but I have one more question.Do the variable names in PHP script have to be same as variable names in shell script?

Comment: no, you can assign a different name in shell script but `grep "^\$DATABASE_HOST="` this should be same as in the php script.

Comment: Another error arises when I declare PHP variables as strings,the error says cant connect to database with user ' 'USERNAME' something like this.How should I avoid this?

Comment: better to echo first the variable and verify its value, its might be empty

Comment: I echoed the variable and it wasn't empty I think the error has to do something with braces.

Comment: okay then remove the `{}` and just use `$DATABASE_USER` in mysql connection

Comment: I am sorry for the delay that took me to reply for this,it did not work Adiii.

Comment: this was missing `DATABASE_USER` in connection PHP

Comment: what I did was I declared PHP variable like $DATABASE_USER='test_user' and access that variable in shell script like you said.But I keep getting an error like this '@'localhost' (using password: YES)or user ''test_user';

Comment: so the password and user name is not correct pass the correct username and password. the bash script work fine.

Comment: Can you take a look at the following codes and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: <?php 
   $DATABASE='db_name';
   $DB_HOST='localhost';
    $PASSWORD='123456';
    $USER='test_user';
    ?>

Comment: DB_HOST='localhost'
DB_NAME='db_name'
USER=$(cat $DB_FILE_NAME | grep "^\$USER=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
PASSWORD=$(cat $DB_FILE_NAME | grep "^\$PASSWORD=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
results=($(mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $USER -p$PASSWORD $DB_NAME -Bse "SELECT a,b,c from test WHERE c='x'"))